# Bookmarklet doesn't work in IE9 when dragged from hyperlink but works after editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, internet-explorer-9, bookmarklet

I created a bookmarklet to load data from my site to a dialog on a third party site.

- This is to assist the users of the third party site with a feature that is otherwise tedious when done manually.
- The bookmarklet works when dragged from an image hyperlink to the favourites/bookmark bars in Chrome and Firefox
- In IE(9) however I'm only able to get it going is by editing the hyperlink by changing some data and putting it back then clicking OK. The content is UNCHANGED

I've pasted a generic version of my script below

```
function loadScript(url, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    if (script.readyState) {
        script.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (script.readyState == "loaded"
                    || script.readyState == "complete") {
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {
        script.onload = function() {
            callback();
        };
    }
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
if (typeof (runMyCode) == "undefined") {
    loadScript(
            "http://mysite/myscript.js",
            function() {
                runMyCode();
            });
} else {
    runMyCode();
}
```

If I remove say, the last semicolon and save the bookmarklet, it works :/

Edit: Added html below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>My tile</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="favicon.ico">        
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:function loadScript(url, callback) {    var script = document.createElement(&quot;script&quot;);    script.type = &quot;text/javascript&quot;;  if(script.readyState) {     script.onreadystatechange = function() {            if (script.readyState == &quot;loaded&quot;                 || script.readyState == &quot;complete&quot;) {     script.onreadystatechange = null;   callback();         }       };  } else {    script.onload = function() {            callback();     };  }   script.src = url;   document.getElementsByTagName(&quot;head&quot;)[0].appendChild(script);}if (typeof(runMyCode) == &quot;undefined&quot;) {loadScript(&quot;http://mysite/myscript.js&quot;,function() {runMyCode();});} else{ runMyCode();}"
title="Drag me to your Bookmark and click me to check your remaining tiles in a game">
<img border="0" alt="My Alt Text" src="http://mysite/myimage" />
</a>

<br/>
<span>Drag the image above to your bookmarks toolbar<br/>and more text</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with the code, and everything to do with either how  you encoded the href value or the fact you are hyperlinking an image. I suggest you test first with a much more simplified test bookmarklet. Also, I suggest you post the actual HTML code, or as close to it as possible.

Comment: I will post the html code. I had tested a simpler bookmarklet from a regular hyperlink that worked. I'll try using a regular hyperlink if the browser is IE if that turns out to be the problem.

Comment: "I had tested a simpler bookmarklet from a regular hyperlink" - test a simpler bookmarklet using a hyperlinked image. Also, try replacing all spaces in the href value with "%20" and eliminating any tabs. Also try out one or a few of these: http://www.google.com/search?q=bookmarklet+creator%7Cmaker%7Ccompiler

Comment: I tested the same link with a regular hyperlink and it didn't work until edited so I doubt it's the image. I'll try encoding the spaces as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks a million @DG. Encoding the spaces did the trick. I noticed firefox automatically did the encoding so I thought nothing of it in IE9. 
The fact that the script worked in IE9 when edited without changing the content had me puzzled.